# Postgres query to get date and total amount grouped by day

Tags: postgresql

I have a table Logs with fields 
Amount,date
I need to get the sum of amount and months grouped by each day

I need to migrate my sqlite code to postgresql but i find the code migration kind of hard.The sqlite code is as follows

```
SELECT SUM(amount),transaction_date FROM log WHERE user_id = 1 AND strftime('%Y', transaction_date) = '2019' GROUP BY strftime('%d', transaction_date);
```

What i need to is date and total amount grouped by day for the year 2019

Comment: Now its working fine thanks to @forpas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `extract()` function instead of `strftime()` to get the year and cast `transaction_date` to date only if it is `timestamp`, if it is of data type `date` remove the casting `::date`:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(amount),
  transaction_date::date 
  FROM log WHERE user_id = 1 AND extract(year from transaction_date) = 2019 
GROUP BY transaction_date::date
```

Comment: I tried the same with other query of mine but not working as expected.The query is as follows 
SELECT SUM(amount),category,transaction_date FROM log WHERE user_id = {current_user.id} AND strftime('%m', transaction_date) = '{month}' GROUP BY category ;

Comment: If you select `transaction_date` you must add it in group by: `group by category, transaction_date`. Postgres is not sqlite which allows non standard sql. Also don't use strftime but extract().

Comment: Thanks for the info mate.I guess i need to go through postgres docs :)